# Autodesk Forge Viewer Exporter get coordinate

Tags: autodesk-forge

How can I get the coordinates of the model or the current object in it? Is it possible to set a mark giving it the coordinates? If possible what functions are used to realise it?

Answer (score 0):

During translation the geometry moves to around origin and it does **NOT** preserve the same coordinates as the original (seed) file, for instance, if you have a large DWG that represents a terrain at a lat long coordinate, the lat long will not be preserved.